# How to execute cabal?

Tags: compiler, haskell

I installed *stack* via binary package on stack's site.
Now I want to use cabal to install packages.

```
cabal install something
```

but it outputs:

```
cabal: The program 'ghc' version >=6.4 is required but it could not be found.
```

Don't know how to check verison, but GHCi is recent:

```
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
```

GHC is not in my PATH, I use it via

```
stack ghc ...
```

But it seems very stripped, as suggests only small set of avaiable options:

```
Usage: stack ghc [-- ARGS (e.g. stack runghc -- X.hs -o x)] ([--plain] |
                 [--[no-]ghc-package-path] [--[no-]stack-exe] [--package ARG]
                 [--rts-options RTSFLAG] [--cwd DIR]) [--help]
  Run ghc

Available options:
  --plain                  Use an unmodified environment (only useful with
                           Docker)
  --[no-]ghc-package-path  Enable/disable setting the GHC_PACKAGE_PATH variable
                           for the subprocess
  --[no-]stack-exe         Enable/disable setting the STACK_EXE environment
                           variable to the path for the stack executable
  --package ARG            Additional packages that must be installed
  --rts-options RTSFLAG    Explicit RTS options to pass to application
  --cwd DIR                Sets the working directory before executing
  --help                   Show this help text

Run 'stack --help' for global options that apply to all subcommands.
```

How to get full ghc working without installing it via package manager or building from source, just by using `stack` facilities?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `stack`, you have to stop using `cabal install <packae-name>`. You could use `stack install <packae-name>` instead.

See:

- [Start your new project](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#start-your-new-project)
- [Why is stack not cabal?](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/06/why-is-stack-not-cabal)

Comment: thanks, but the question was about getting non-stripped ghc, that cabal could use.